# 10.04.4 unresponsive

Tags: 10.04, upgrade

I just updated to Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.  But after the update, my computer is unresponsive.

I used to be able to click on my name, then I would be prompted to enter my password. This is no longer available, and I no longer have access to anything on my laptop.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, can you login that way?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the update completed?

try logging in with

```
Crtl+Alt+F1
```

then perform your update again.

Comment: I used the crtl command which got never to the black screen, but how do I perform the update from there?

Comment: When I log in there, it says to check my BIOS settings or run: /usr/bin/check-bios-nx --verbose